# multithreading in c in a mmorpg

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety

I want to use multithreading in my mmorpg in c++, ive got 5 threads at the moment, and i want to split another one in two, but my mmorpg server conists of loads of vectors, and because the vectors arn't threadsafe to write, i can't do it properly.

Is there an alternative to using vectors across threads, or is there a way to make the vector read/write multithread safe.

Heres an example of what i wan't, try to find an alternative to something like this:
Obviously this isn't actual code, im just making an example.

```
//Thread1
//Load monster and send data to the player
globals::monstername[myid];//Myid = 1 for now -.-
senddata(globals::monstername[myid]);//Not the actual networking code, im just lazy.

//Thread2
//Create a monster and manage it
globals::monstername.push_back("FatBlobMonster");
//More managing code i cant be bothered inserting >.<
```

Answer (score 6):

Two things.

1. Don't store shared data in one big data structure that gets locked completely. Lock just parts of it. For example, if you must use vectors, then create a set of locks for regions of the vector. Say I have 1000 entries, I might create 10 locks, that each lock 100 consecutive entries. But you can probably do better. For example, store your monsters in a hash table, where each "bucket" in your hash table has its own lock.
2. Use a "read/write" lock. It is possible to create a type of lock that allows multiple readers and a single writer. So each hash bucket might have a read write lock. If no monsters are being created in a particular bucket, then multiple threads can be reading monsters out of that bucket. If you need to hash a new monster into the bucket then you lock the bucket for writing. This lock will wait for all current readers to release, and not allow more readers to lock until the write is complete. Once there are no more readers, the w rite operation succeeeds

Comment: You can lock specific parts of a vector? Or are you saying use multiple vectors and lock those individually?

Comment: If your vector has to reallocate itself as it grows then you have to lock the whole thing on a resize. But unless a resize happens, and if elements can stay at same the offset for the duration then you can lock individual parts of the array. But that isn't really the point. The point is to use a data structure that can be locked in parts. A list of sub arrays would work also.

Comment: Interesting. And yes, I understood why, just didn't know you can lock down parts of vectors/arrays.

Answer (score 4):

I am not aware of any thread safe vector class. However, you could create one yourself that uses `std::vector` and a `std::mutex` (in C++11):

```
template <typename T>
class LockedVector {

private:
    std::mutex m;
    std::vector<T> vec;
};
```

You lock the mutex with `std::lock`.

Comment: Thankyou, can you please explain how to use this and how it works? :)

Comment: This won't work very well. Because you are locking the whole array. So while you can have multiple threads - they will be all waiting on each other to access the vector. So operations on the vector will have the same performance characteristics as if they were in a single thread.